# Are MKMapView GEOErrorDomain codes documented anywhere?

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkmapviewdelegate

Apple provides a method in MKMapViewDelegate for handling map view errors.

```
- (void)mapViewDidFailLoadingMap:(MKMapView *)mapView 
                   withError:(NSError *)error;
```

A few of our users complained about map tiles not loading, so we added tracking in Crashlytics. We're seeing a bunch of different error codes all falling under the `GEOErrorDomain` domain.

Some of the codes we're seeing: -204, -218, -209, -7, -602

The only problem is that these errors have no localized descriptions recorded by Crashlytics, and I can't seem to find documentation on these anywhere. Are these errors documented anywhere?

Comment: Not documented anywhere.  -204 means `IncompleteResponse` though. I've gotten that before and the userInfoDictionary had that key + a description of what it was trying to do. GEOErrorDomain seems to mostly be server errors.. -7 means it cannot find your country. Base on the above error codes, you are most likely requesting invalid locations/regions.

Comment: I've a -204, detailed as "failed because of Invalid Response"; not found a solution yet. I'm on iPad Mini 9.3, all ok in Simulator, or a Device running 12.6.